# How to find something in a vector

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I've got a pointer to a Vector with buildings.

```
vector<building> * building1;
building1 = gamer.getBuilding(); ( building1 is a pointer to vector with all buildings that gamer has on that moment. )
```

Now I want to check if in that vector a building exist called for example house..

I thought I could do something like

```
vector<building>::iterator it;

it = find((*building1).begin(), (*building1).end(),buildings::house);
```

where buildings is an enum.

but this doens't work.

Can someone help me?

kind regards,

Comment: So `building` is a class and `buildings` is an enum? How confusing...

Comment: Do you have something against the `->` operator?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `std::find_if`. It requires a predicate as third argument. So you can write a function or a function object, and use that as predicate. The syntax of usage would be:

```
std::vector<building>::iterator it = std::find_if(v.begin(), 
                                                    v.end(), 
                                                    predicate);
```

And in C++11, you can use lambda directly as:

```
auto it = std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), 
                           [](const building & b)
                           {
                               //your code: which object you want to find?
                               //for example
                               return b.Name == "GhostBuilding";
                           });
```

Note the usage of `auto` as well.

Answer (score 3):

The answer would depend on the definition of `building`, which you don't show. But in general, when you don't want to find by value but by predicate you would use `find_if`:

```
struct building_of_type
{
public:
    explicit building_of_type( buildings type ) : _type( type ){}

    bool operator ()( building const& b ) const {  return is b of type _type?; }
private:
    buildings const _type;
};

std::find_if(
    building1->begin(), building1->end()
  , building_of_type( buildings::house )
);
```

or for simpler cases:

```
bool is_building_a_house( building const& b ){ return is b of type house?; }

std::find_if(
    building1->begin(), building1->end()
  , is_building_a_house
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::find_if` with a `binary_function` for that :

```
struct BuildingExistsPredicate : public std::binary_function<BuildingType, std::string, bool> {
    bool operator()(const BuildingType& building, const std::string& name) const {
        return building.name == name;
    }
};
```

then

```
vector<BuildingType> *building1 = gamer.getBuilding();
vector<BuildingType>::iterator it = std::find_if(building1->begin(), building1->end(), std::bind2nd(BuildingExistsPredicate(), "house"));

if(it == building1->end()) {
    std::cerr << "Building not found\n";
    return;
}

// it now points to the first building whose name is "house"
```

If the item is found, `it` will point to it. Otherwise, `it` will point to `building1->end()`